# In angularjs how should I chain services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular js, so bear with me.

First what I am trying to do is have my angular app be divided into modules with two common services going between them, one which will hold the config, and another api-service to communicate with the backend server. Also most of the config, like theme, user permissions, e.t.c I wish to fetch from the server instead of coding it right within the app.

I am using https://github.com/keshavos/generator-angularjs-cordova as a basis for my app.

To test things out, I wrote(generated) two services,

```
/app/modules/core/services/api-service.js
'use strict';

angular
    .module('core')
    .service('ApiService', [

        function() {

            //alert(SessionConfig.getConst("SERVER_URL"));
            this.config = {
                'site':'http://localhost:1337'
            }

            this.getConfig = function() {
                return this.config;
            };

        }
    ]);
```

The session config is supposed to contain the actual configurations

```
/app/modules/core/services/session-config.js
'use strict';

angular
    .module('core')
    .service('SessionConfig', [

        function() {
            this.config_const = {
                "SERVER_URL" : "http://localhost:1337",
            };

            this.config_vars = {
                "user" : {},
                "theme": "default"
            };

            this.getConst = function() {
                return true;
            };

        }
    ]);
```

Then I try to include them in the home controller like

```
/app/modules/core/controllers/home.js
'use strict';

angular
    .module('core')
    .config(['$sailsProvider', function ($sailsProvider) {
        $sailsProvider.url = 'http://localhost:1337';
    }])
    .controller('HomeController', ['$scope','$sails', 'SessionConfig',
        function($scope,$sails,SessionConfig) {
```

The above throws error `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: SessionConfigProvider <- SessionConfig`

However when I try including the ApiService in a similar way, it works ok

```
])
    .controller('HomeController', ['$scope','$sails', 'ApiService',
        function($scope,$sails,ApiService) {
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you forget to include the file in script tag?

Comment: @charlietfl, no because that pack automatically pulls all scripts and includes as necessary. Between `SessionConfig` and `ApiService` there is little to no difference how they are coded or called in homeController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try abstract your services into separate modules, then inject those into your app. So you could have

```
var apiService = angular.module('apiService', []);

apiService.factory('$apiService', function() {
   return
      {
       someFunction: function() {
          //do some stuff
         }  
      }  
});
```

Do the same for your SessionConfig

```
var sessionConfig = angular.module('sessionConfig', []);

sessionConfig.factory('$sessionConfig', function() {
   return
      {
       someFunction: function() {
          //do some stuff
         }  
      }  
});
```

Then when you initialise your app you can go

```
var coreApp = angular.module('coreApp', ['apiService', 'sessionConfig']);
```

Then your controller

```
coreApp.controller('myCtrl', function($apiService, $sessionConfig) {
    $apiService.someFunction();
    $sessionConfig.someFunction();
});
```

The services essentially return an object on which you call the methods you defined within them, using dot notation. It's essentially what you have, this is just how I would go about organising it as I personally find it a bit clearer!

Hope that helps somewhat!

Edit to show keeping both services in same module

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('$serviceOne', function(){
  return {
      serviceOneFunction: function() {
         //do something
         }
     }
});

app.factory('$serviceTwo', function(){
  return {
     serviceTwoFunction: function() {
         //do something 
         }
     }
});

app.controller('myCtrl', function($serviceOne, $serviceTwo) {
    $serviceOne.serviceOneFunction();
    $serviceTwo.serviceTwoFunction();
});
```

Here's a working fiddle of what your trying to implement

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19285/

Comment: why would this help? Creating a module for each service really doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: Well I guess from reading the OP's first line "First what I am trying to do is have my angular app be divided into modules with two common services going between them" personally I think it would be cleaner, and easier to maintain, to keep the services in separate modules.

Comment: My idea of a module is pretty much the different units of the site. So say user module, cart module, authentication module e.t.c. Is there no way of keeping multiple related services together within a module in angular?

Comment: Added an example of keeping both services in same module.

Comment: Cheers :) added a fiddle too just in case!